# PHP consecutive occurrence of characters replace with other parameter

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like

```
sadd*sadasdsdsad*sdadsdasdad*asdsadsadsadasdsdsd*asdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasd*asdasdadasdsdasd*asdsaddasdasdas*
```

now i want all consecutive *'s to be replaced with `<b> & </b>` respectively. Above string will become

```
sadd<b>sadasdsdsad</b>sdadsdasdad<b>asdsadsadsadasdsdsd</b>asdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasd<b>asdasdadasdsdasd</b>asdsaddasdasdas*sdfdsfsd
```

the last * is not replaced because there is no consecutive pair of star left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could simply do

```
\*(.+?)((?=$)|\*)
# match a star
# anything else lazily afterwards
# the end of the string
# or another star
```

And replace this with `<b>$1</b>`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aCYdLX/3).

Comment: the last star is getting replaced to <b></b> check same demo at regex101.com

Comment: @user609306: Right, adjusted to match at least one character. It's always better to escape special characters like the star.

Comment: finally i used this one in PHP 
echo preg_replace('/\*(.*?)\*/', '<b>$1</b>',$string);